# Changing part of file (txt) in Python?

Tags: python, file, yaml

I was wondering if it's possible to change part of one line in txt/yaml file using Python?

I have file like this:

```
main:
  Player1:
    points: 5
  Player2:
    points: 2
```

What I want is to change points for specified player(i.e. Player1 has 5 points, I want to change it to 10)? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Selcuk tbh, nothing at all, since I don't even know where to start, I'm looking at white space for hour lol..

Comment: You can easily change a specific character to another (look into random file access) but to go from 5 to 10 requires inserting a character. To do this, you'll have to read the file, make your change, and write out the new file.

Comment: Use [PyYAML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML) ([docs](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation))

Answer (score 2):

The smartest way to achieve what you want is to parse the yaml file, make the change to the parsed content and then rewrite the file.

This is much more robust than somehow messing with the raw file. You have data in a valid, specified representation (yaml), and it makes sense to use it.

you need to install pyYAML first, so you have the code to parse the file. (use easy install or pip).

The snippet below does what you need. I annotated every line to tell you what it does. I encourage you to understand every single line and not just copy paste this example, because thats how you learn a programming language.

```
# the library you need to parse the yaml file
import yaml
# maybe you are on Python3, maybe not, so this makes the print function work
# further down
from __future__ import print_function

#this reads the file and closes it once the with statement is over
with open('source.yml', 'r') as file_stream:
    # this parses the file into a dict, so yml_content is then a dict
    # you can freely change
    yml_content = yaml.load(file_stream)

# proof that yml_content now contains your data as a dict
print(yml_content)

# make the change
yml_content['main']['Player1']['points'] = 10

#proof that yml_content now contains changed data
print(yml_content)

# transform the dict back to a string (default_flow_style makes the
# representation of the yml equal to the original file)
yml_string = yaml.dump(yml_content, default_flow_style=False)

# open a the file in write mode, transform the dict to a valid yml string
# write the string to the file, close the file
with open('source.yml', 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(yml_string)
```

Comment: +1 Nice first answer. Keep it coming.